postgres json column type with Micronaut
json_build_object does exactly what I want except the resulting JSON object is being encoded in my Micronaut controller's JSON response output as:
"active": {
"type": "json",
"value": "{\"p10\": 0.00, \"p25\": 0.95, \"p75\": 49.69, \"p90\": 105.09, \"median\": 15.82}",
"null": false
},

instead of:
"active": {"p10": 0.00, "p25": 0.95, "p75": 49.69, "p90": 105.09, "median": 15.82}

Anyone know what might be going on here?
edit to add the postscript:  I discovered this isn't particular to json_build_object(), it happens for postgres columns of type json/jsonb as well.

I just needed to use jackson's ObjectMapper to map the value to an Object.
